# retrieving multiple dictionaries in list type from file python

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, dictionary, formatting

I want to retrieve the dictionaries of a list after having passed that list to a file. But I lose the format of the contents of the list when I write it in a text. How can I recover this data formatted in dictionaries types again?

first I created a list with two dimensions. then I filled in the values ​​with empty dictionaries and dictionaries with values.

```
dataValue = {
        'telefone': '6298855663311',
        'nome': '', 
        'pagamento': 'Boleto', 
        'embarque': '16:00'
}

emptyDi = {}

assentosMatriz2D = [

        [dataValue, emptyDi, emptyDi, emptyDi, emptyDi],
        
        [emptyDi, emptyDi, emptyDi, emptyDi, emptyDi],
        
    [emptyDi, emptyDi, dataValue, emptyDi, emptyDi]

    ]

print(assentosMatriz2D[0][1])

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines("%s\n" % place for place in assentosMatriz2D)

# define empty list
linhas = []

# open file and read the content in a list
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    filecontents = f.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        current_place = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        linhas.append(current_place)

create_lt = linhas[1]

print(create_lt[0][0])

print(f'the firt line {create_lt}')

output:::::
>>{}
>>[
>>the firt line [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to retrieve a dict passed as a string, you can use `eval` (`current_place = eval(line[:-1])`) but as it can run code it's very unsecure, don't do it if you don't trust the source. the most common way of storing dicts is json

```
import json
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(assentosMatriz2D, f)

# open file and read the content in a list
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    assentosMatriz2D = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, including this tip about safety! very important, but luckily this code is for college